# python - Simulating 'else' in dictionary switch statements

Tags: python, switch-statement, case, if-statement

I'm working on a project which used a load of `If, Elif, Elif, ...Else` structures, which I later changed for switch-like statements, as shown [here](http://vedang.me/techlog/2011/08/07/switch-statements-in-python/) and [here](http://bytebaker.com/2008/11/03/switch-case-statement-in-python/).

How would I go about adding a general "Hey, that option doesn't exist" case similar to an Else in an `If, Elif, Else` statement - something that gets executed if none of the `If`s or `Elif`s get to run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could catch the `KeyError` error that ensues when a value is not found in the map, and return or process there a default value. For example, with `n = 3` this piece of code:

```
if n == 1:
    print 'one'
elif n == 2:
    print 'two'
else:
    print 'too big!'
```

Becomes this:

```
choices = {1:'one', 2:'two'}
try:
    print choices[n]
except KeyError:
    print 'too big!'
```

Either way, `'too big!'` gets printed on the console.

Comment: Ah, so simple, how did I not see it in the first place!
Thanks anyway, I'm sure someone else could get some help out of this too :P

Comment: Oh, of course. Let me just try it out first - I'm only one man! :P

Answer (score 9):

If the else is really not an exceptional situation, would it not be better to use the optional parameter for get?

```
>>> choices = {1:'one', 2:'two'}
>>> print choices.get(n, 'too big!')

>>> n = 1
>>> print choices.get(n, 'too big!')
one

>>> n = 5
>>> print choices.get(n, 'too big!')
too big!
```

Answer (score 2):

The [first article](http://vedang.me/techlog/2011/08/07/switch-statements-in-python/) you linked to had a very clean solution:

```
response_map = {
    "this": do_this_with,
    "that": do_that_with,
    "huh": duh
}
response_map.get( response, prevent_horrible_crash )( data )
```

This will call `prevent_horrible_crash` if `response` is not one of the three choices listed in `response_map`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a function f(a,b) and different setups of parameters according to the value of some variable x. So you want to execute f with a=1 and b=3 if x='Monday' and if x='Saturday' you want to execute f with a=5 and b=9. Otherwise you will print that such value of x is not supported.

I would do

```
from functools import partial
def f(a,b):
 print("A is %s and B is %s" % (a,b))

def main(x):
 switcher = {
             "Monday": partial(f,a=1, b=3),
             "Saturday": partial(f, a=5, b=9)
            }
 if x not in switcher.keys():
  print("X value not supported")
  return

 switcher[x]()
```

this way f is not executed on declaration of switcher but at the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Some one-line alternatives:

```
choices = {1:'one', 2:'two'}
key = 3

# returns the provided default value if the key is not in the dictionary
print(choices[key] if key in choices else 'default_value')

# or using the dictionary get() method
print(choices.get(key, 'default_value')
```